# How can I derive posterior distribution of theta when having 2 R.V (X, y) using Bayesian Rule?

Tags: bayesian, bayes-theorem

In the book, *Machine Learning in Finance: From Theory to Practice(Matthew F. Dixon, et al, 2020)*, there is a bayesian equation derivation in Chapter2:

$p(\theta|y, X) = {p(\theta, y | X) \over p(y|X)} = {p(\theta)p(y|\theta, X) \over p(y|X)}$

I have two questions about this:

1. How can I interpret $p(\theta|y, X)$? Should I see it as $p(\theta|(y \cap X))$ or $p((\theta|y), X)$?
2. How is the above equation derived? I have no idea how $p(\theta|y, X)$ goes to ${p(\theta, y | X) \over p(y|X)}$ (why is it normalized(?) by X on both nominator and denominator? and why $p(y|X)$ should be denominator?, etc), and how ${p(\theta, y | X) \over p(y|X)}$ is converted to
   ${p(\theta)p(y|\theta, X) \over p(y|X)}$ suddenly(How can the $p(\theta)$ came out of $p(\theta, y | X)$?, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $P(\theta \mid y, X)$ denotes the conditional probability/density of $\theta$ given $y$ and $X$. $p((\theta \mid y), X)$ is definitely wrong. $p(\theta \mid (y \cap X))$ is in the right spirit, but I would not use the $\cap$ notation because $y$ and $X$ are presumably random variables, not events.
2. You should be familiar with $$p(\theta \mid y) = \frac{p(\theta, y)}{p(y)} = \frac{p(\theta) p(y \mid \theta)}{p(y)}.$$ This is simply the definition of conditional probability applied twice (and is often called Bayes's rule). What you have is a similar application, where each of the five terms appearing in this equation is also conditioned on $X$, i.e. $$p(\theta \mid y, X) = \frac{p(\theta, y \mid X)}{p(y \mid X)} = \frac{p(\theta \mid X) p(y \mid \theta, X)}{p(y \mid X)}.$$ If this is unclear to you, I would encourage you to just break every conditional probability down into unconditional probabilities, and check that the equalities work out i.e. $p(\theta \mid y, X) = \frac{p(\theta, y, X)}{p(y, X)}$, $p(y \mid X) = \frac{p(y, X)}{p(X)}$, and so on.
3. Finally, the reason why $p(\theta \mid X)$ is replaced by $p(\theta)$ is probably due to some context that you did not provide in the question. I presume that $y$ depends on both $\theta$ and $X$, but $\theta$ does not depend on $X$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. You said "break every conditional probability down into unconditional probabilities" and I really did and now I got to know. But this is like "Hey, you got the answer sheet and thinking it a reverse way" What I want to know is, if I have only $p(\theta, y| X)$ without the answer(which is $p(\theta|X)p(y|\theta, x)$), why should I convert it to $p(\theta|X)p(y|\theta, x)$ exactly even though there are other forms exist?

Comment: @user3595632 Without context, you are right that there are many different ways to write the same probability. However, in the context of a Bayesian setup, you know certain conditional distributions but not others. This is the main purpose of Bayes's rule: to write a conditional distribution in terms of probabilities that are available to you. I am guessing that in your setup you are given the distributions $p(y \mid X, \theta)$ and $p(\theta) = p(\theta \mid X)$, so it makes sense to try to write $p(\theta \mid y, X)$ in terms of these probabilities that you know.

Comment: Thanks for advice!